# How to display the vertical upwards arrow?

Tags: arrows

The following sytax creates a square diagram with its corners labelled as (top left) a --->b then the bottom two corners (left to right) is c ---> d .

I can display a vertical downward arrow pointing downwards from a to c and from b to d respectively using VV command. How can I reverse the direction of the vertical downwards arrow so that the direction is now from c to a and d to b instead? I am using the editor TexMaker running on Windows.

```
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{a} @>{f}>> \mathcal{b}\\
@V{S}VV @V{S}VV \\
c @>{\sigma}>> d\end{CD}
$$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tikz-cd`.  It is way simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  a \ar[r,"f"]                & b            \\
  c \ar[u,"S"]\ar[r,"\sigma"] & d \ar[u,"S"] \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you insist on using `amscd`, the `A` specifier stands for upwards arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{CD}
    a @>{f}>> b \\
    @A{S}AA @A{S}AA \\
    c @>{\sigma}>> d
  \end{CD}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer with 2 options. The first option using tikz-cd did not work for me because there was compilation error for the line \usetikzlibrary{cd}. Probably I don't have tikz. The second option worked fine.